# findviewbyid returns null in a dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a custom dialog and when I try to get the value of an EditText it returns null.

This line returns null

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
```

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(TicTacToe.this)
            //.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
            .setTitle(getTitleText())
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton("JOIN GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    try
                    {
                        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
                            playerName = et.getText().toString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            })
            .create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 50):

In my case:
First I must call the

> dialog.show(),

and only after it I was able to use

> dialog.findviewById(R.id.myID).

If I missed to call the show(), than I got a null back with findViewByID.

Comment: That's totally contrary to what `AlertDialog.Builder.create()` seems to imply, and also, totally correct.  In fact, even if you don't dereference the null, simply having called `findViewById` will cause a different exception to be thrown when you finally do call `show()`.  Thanks.

Comment: That's so weird... and by the way device-dependent. I have used `Dialog.findViewById()` before calling `Dialog.show()` and it worked.

Comment: I called it after `show()` but it's still null.

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
```

You have to tell in which view to find the id. Otherwise it will try to find the id in the view from the xml layout inflated by `setContentView` (usually declared in `onCreate`)

Answer (score 18):

I faced a similar problem. In my case, I had a dialog with custom layout and in this layout had a radioButton. In order to solve that, I used the follow code:

```
View dialogLayout = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
dialog.setView(dialogLayout);

RadioButton radiobt = (RadioButton) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.radioBt);
```

Comment: This answer helped me get my states dropdown spinner showing with:

`LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_change_city_and_state_dialog, null);
builder.setView(dialogLayout);
dialogStatesDropdown = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialogStatesDropdown);`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, which presented itself in the following code snippet:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.addbank_dialog);
dialog.show();

Button btnSaveBank = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveBank);

final EditText etBankName = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etBankName);

btnSaveBank.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            String bank = etBankName.getText().toString();
            SharedCommonData.dbOps.saveBankInDB(bank);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(SharedCommonData.context, "Bank Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        refreshBanks();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

`etBankName` was returning null value, but then I used `dialog.findviewbyid(R.id.etBankName)` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this error because I was redeclaring an initialized variable

In main Activity I had:

```
EditText cityName;
```

And in onCreate:

```
EditText cityName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cityName);
```

Just removed EditText and smooth sailing!

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for me, so I started trying different lifecycle hooks, and the one that worked for me was `onViewCreated`, which seems like a good choice semantically as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I did was that I was passing an ID of a view which was in different fragment and in that case the compiler gave me same error.
So try checking that the ID use pass is in the same xml which is connect to the java file.
I hope it helps this is my first ever solution given in this community.