# Button Click Error In Dialog Box

Tags: android, dialog

In my app, I use a Dialog box that loads a layout in itself.

When I click on the button that is in dialog (a button in loaded layout in Dialog box), my app crashes with the message, *Unfortunately app is stopped*. The critical section of code is below.

```
void contact_list_dialog()
{
   dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test);

   b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   b1.setOnClickListener(this);

   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   dialog.setTitle("ListView");

   dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
   dialog.getWindow().setLayout(300, 500);

   dialog.show();
}
```

Logcat :

```
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at com.sms.card.offline.MainActivity.contact_list_dialog(MainActivity.java:184)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at com.sms.card.offline.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:304)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)  
01-01 15:34:46.700: E/AndroidRuntime(13044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findviewbyid returns null in a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525500/findviewbyid-returns-null-in-a-dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
b1=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You are not getting button properly. That gives you `NullPointerException`. You should use `dialog.` to initialize dialog's views.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry - I've another ask ; i use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in my manifest for disable focus in app starup, but my textview set focused yet.