# Custom cancel button in fragment's AlertDialog's click event not handled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-button

I have created a dialog whose layout and cancel and submit buttons are entirely customized, thanks to a layout. I would want to handle click on both buttons - in particular, we consider in this question the cancel button.

## The problem

When the cancel button is clicked, the click event handler isn't executed.

## Implementation

### Explanations

I created a dialog fragment. Within, I use the dialogs builder to create my dialog (as recommended by the official documentation). I set the click handler for the cancel button and cancel the dialog within.

The cancel button is clickable (as specified in the layout file). Thus, the event is normally well triggered. It just seems to be no handled.

### Sources

#### DialogFragment.java

NB : in the following, the output "ok" isn't shown, whereas the output displaying the button reference is. It means that the function that sets the click event handler is executed (and that the button is correctly got from the layout), but that the click event handler isn't even when a click is performed.

```
    public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
            builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            setCancelButtonListener((Button) Objects.requireNonNull(view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel)), dialog);
            return dialog;
        }
    private void setCancelButtonListener(Button button, final Dialog dialog) {
        System.out.println(button);
        button.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("ok");
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

#### dialog.xml (*i.e.:* the cancel button in the XML layout of the fragment)

```
    <Button
        android:clickable="true"

        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_button"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/colorRoyalRedLight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_4" />
```

## Question

Why is the button click event not handled? How to make it work?

Comment: use builder.setView(view) after inflating (LayoutInflater.from..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these two lines from your code:

```
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
```

Here, you give the resource id of your layout to the `AlertDialog.Builder` so it will use it to populate the `AlertDialog`'s "customizable" area. (You can achieve the same effect by first inflating a `View` and then calling `AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View)`)

Next, you let `LayoutInflater` create a `View` by inflating *the same layout file once more*. This new `View` is accessible by a local variable *view* in `onCreateDialog()` but it is never added to any `ViewGroup` so it will never actually be shown. Because the `Button` contained in this `View` can't be clicked, its `OnClickListener` will never fire.

So you should set up the `AlertDialog` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setView(view);
Dialog dialog = builder.create();
setCancelButtonListener((Button) Objects.requireNonNull(view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel)), dialog);
return dialog;
```

Comment: I was working on this problem since several hours, and didn't even realize this very idiot error...! Thank you for help! Would it be possible to use `builder.setView(R.layout.dialog);` and make a call to a sort of `builder.getView`, avoiding the use of the inflater?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - there seems to be no `getView()` for `AlertDialog.Builder`. But you can get the `Button` by using `dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.button_cancel)`

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.button_cancel)` returns null unfortunately (the decor view exists, but the button isn't found, thus `findViewById` returns null)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler - then maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847763/5015207) will help you. Please note that the behavior of some approaches even seems to be depending on the device. IMHO, it looks like first inflating the layout and then getting the Button from the resulting View is a lot more straightforward and reliable than any other approach.