# Dialog in a Fragment :

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

im trying to add a dialog in my Fragment. I've got a MainActivity (Drawer menu) which cointains my Fragments. In one Fragment i want to show a Dialog but i always get null object reference when i try to change things in the view / or try to implement action listener.

```
public class Fragment_Statistik extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView currentBerrys,currentFish,currentTrees,currentLumber,currentStones,currentStonebricks;
ProgressBar progressBarBerrys, progressBarFish, progressBarTrees,progressBarLumber,progressBarStones,progressBarStonebricks;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Button upgrade;
boolean running = true;
Dialog popupUpgradeWarehouse;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statistik, container, false);

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    fab = getView().findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    currentBerrys = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_berrys);
    currentFish = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_fish);
    currentTrees = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_trees);
    currentLumber = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_lumber);
    currentStones = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_stone);
    currentStonebricks = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_current_stonebricks);
    progressBarBerrys = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarBerrys);
    progressBarFish = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarFish);
    progressBarTrees = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarTree);
    progressBarLumber = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarLumber);
    progressBarStones = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarStone);
    progressBarStonebricks = getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBarStonebrick);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    popupUpgradeWarehouse = new Dialog(getContext());}
```

The showPopupupgradeWarehouse works. I get the Dialog shown when i delete all other code.

```
    public void showPopupUpgradeWarehouse() {
    popupUpgradeWarehouse.setContentView(R.layout.popup_upgrade_warehouse);
    upgrade = getView().findViewById(R.id.popupButtonUpgrade);
    ImageView popupImageViewClose;
    popupImageViewClose = getView().findViewById(R.id.popupImageViewClose);

    upgrade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    popupUpgradeWarehouse.show();
}
```

Comment: Use `upgrade = popupUpgradeWarehouse.findViewById(R.id.popupButtonUpgrade);`

Comment: this was the problem... Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findviewbyid returns null in a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525500/findviewbyid-returns-null-in-a-dialog)