# Reference an EditText, that is within an external layout that gets set with .setView of an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

The goal is to reference an edittext, that is within an external layout that gets set with `.setView`. The problem is within its initialization.

This is the code

```
AlertDialog dSchreiben = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("Message")
    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layoutwithanEditText, null))
    .setPositiveButton("Positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            EditText taskEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextinLayout);
            //continue
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", null)
    .create();
dSchreiben.show();
```

As you might have guessed, it throws a null reference exception at `EditText taskEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextinLayout);` because I have to put it like `EditText taskEditText = (EditText) dSchreiben.findViewById(R.id.EditTextinLayout);`.

But in the latter case, it cannot find `dSchreiben` because it hasn't been created, yet.

If I replace the `AlertDialog` settings with the explicit object, ie `dSchreiben.setTitle("Title"); dSchreiben.setMessage("Message");` etc, it won't work, because the `AlertDialog` does not inherit a `setPositiveButton` if being used like that.

How to reference `taskEditText` within `onClick`?

Comment: Inflate the layout separately, before setting up the `AlertDialog`, then use the inflated `View` for `setView()` and the `findViewById()` call; e.g., like is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35482390.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, that worked.